# OWIN Authorization Server and External Signin with Google/Facebook

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin

It's been long since I had a question.

Ok, so, I read [this article](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) and downloaded the sample code. Very nice examples of using OWIN to create an Authorization Server with Google signin included. It also includes 4 clients for Authorization Code Grant, Client Credential Grant, Implicit Grant and Resource Owner Password Credential Grant.

for sake of brevity I am going to post here just the configuration Startup file, then my problem and questions. Also, I found my problem using the Implicit Grant client. Here we go...

Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable Application Sign In Cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Application",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            LoginPath = new PathString(Paths.LoginPath),
            LogoutPath = new PathString(Paths.LogoutPath),
        });

        // Enable External Sign In Cookie
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("External");
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "External",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "External",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
        });

        // Enable google authentication
        //var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        //{
        //    Caption = "Google+",
        //    ClientId = "blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        //    ClientSecret = "Q1zNmqf-U3ZffeZgcTPh760j",
        //    CallbackPath = new PathString("/OAuth/Authorize"),
        //    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
        //    {
        //        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        //            {
        //                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value));
        //                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value));
        //                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));
        //                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
        //                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Token", context.AccessToken));
        //            }
        //    }
        //};
        //googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
        //googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication();


        // Setup Authorization Server
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.AuthorizePath),
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.TokenPath),
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,

            // Authorization server provider which controls the lifecycle of Authorization Server
            Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
            {
                OnValidateClientRedirectUri = ValidateClientRedirectUri,
                OnValidateClientAuthentication = ValidateClientAuthentication,
                OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,
                OnGrantClientCredentials = GrantClientCredetails
            },

            // Authorization code provider which creates and receives authorization code
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateAuthenticationCode,
                OnReceive = ReceiveAuthenticationCode,
            },

            // Refresh token provider which creates and receives referesh token
            RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
                OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
            }
        });
    }

    private Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == Clients.Client1.Id)
        {
            context.Validated(Clients.Client1.RedirectUrl);
        }
        else if (context.ClientId == Clients.Client2.Id)
        {
            context.Validated(Clients.Client2.RedirectUrl);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret) ||
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            if (clientId == Clients.Client1.Id && clientSecret == Clients.Client1.Secret)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
            else if (clientId == Clients.Client2.Id && clientSecret == Clients.Client2.Secret)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.UserName, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType), context.Scope.Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));

        context.Validated(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task GrantClientCredetails(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.ClientId, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType), context.Scope.Select(x => new Claim("urn:oauth:scope", x)));

        context.Validated(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }


    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _authenticationCodes =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    private void CreateAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
        _authenticationCodes[context.Token] = context.SerializeTicket();
    }

    private void ReceiveAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        string value;
        if (_authenticationCodes.TryRemove(context.Token, out value))
        {
            context.DeserializeTicket(value);
        }
    }

    private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }

    private void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
    }
}
```

Now, notice that there is a piece of code that has been commented out. Here is the key and confusion.

The original code comes just like this **app.UseGoogleAuthentication();** So, this code works perfect from the get go (and for those who want to download and test this code, it's ready to go, just hit F5).

Now, I understand that this code so far, all is doing is allowing someone "authenticate" using Google just to get a "validated user" response, then creating its own validation/token (LOCAL AUTHORITY).

The problem comes when I want to extend a little bit more that google authentication. I want to actually gather more data from Google (other than just a valid/not valid google user). As soon as I uncomment those lines, the authorization part of the Authorization Server stops. I don't get an exception or anything, it just stays spinning.

Has anyone had experience on this specific issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps it would help to show a browser trace and see what the request is that stops the authorization server and compare it to a successful trace (i.e one that does not use the extra options)